# Is it risky to choose most recent versions of Laravel over LTS versions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am planning to create a web project by using the Laravel framework. I have worked on Laravel 5.1(LTS) and later haven't learned further versions like 6.x and 7.x. For the new project, I need to use some third-party libraries. Are there any differences in these versions? Is the latest LTS version 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 7 is the latest.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x

Some of the differences can be found here.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

Comment: How exact latest current version can be found for Laravel? Just to make sure that doesn't create a new project with some older versions?

Comment: Just look at the documentation. There is a drop-down (top-right) which shows the latest and older versions. You can also see on their GitHub.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel